# Mysql period character in account names

Tags: mysql, special-characters, account, database-administration

Is it possible to use period character in MySQL account names? I checked the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-names.html) and tried to google but haven't found any convincing info.

Comment: What don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: Have you tried creating your own test accounts with periods in them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but you'll have to escape the username with quotes (`"`).

E.g.:

Without quotes:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user name.surname;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.surname' at line 1
```

With quotes:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user "name.surname";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

yes only and only if you are using quotes e.g.

```
create user "myuser.lastname"
```